# How to animate the height of an Animated View dynamically based on the position of another Animated View?

Tags: animation, react-native

Concept: User moves a circle animated view up and down in the y direction on the screen which increases and decreases the height of a separate animated view.

Problem: The "this.state.pan.getLayout()" that is used to move the circle up and down gives an error when computations are made with it.

e.g.

```
position = function() {
  let Window = Dimensions.get('window');
  return {
    height: (Window.height / 2) + this.state.pan.getLayout()
  }
}
```

returns an error [object Object] of type NSString cannot be converted to NSNumber

Answer (score 0):

`getLayout()` method returns an `{left: String, top: String}` for use in `style` attribute. To retrieve the actual number, access `x` and `y` properties directly :

```
position = function() {
    let Window = Dimensions.get('window');
    return {
        height: (Window.height / 2) + this.state.pan.y
    }
}
```

More info : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated.html#getlayout

Comment: Gives this error: JSON value '333.5[object Object]' of type NSString cannot be converted to NSNumber

Comment: I'm mistaken in my post. You're not giving us enoguh details about your code to identify your problem